# Is it secure to keep my webpages(php pages) inside public_html folder on a production server?

Tags: php, apache, security, server

This is my first php project and I'm going make it online very soon. Recently i have read some articles about not keeping the php scripts inside public folder because if the server is not configured correctly php scripts might be visible as pure text and that is a big security concern if those scripts have sensitive information(like DB credentials etc.). But i believe, I shouldn't be concerned. As my php pages are mainly consist of multiple include/require. Here is an example:

```
home.php

<?php
require_once ('../resources/app_config.php');
require_once ('../resources/includes/functions.php');
require_once ('../resources/includes/header.php');
?>
<body>
The body elements...
</body>
<?php
require_once ('../resources/includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Here is the directory structure of my project:

```
resources
  |___ app_config.php
  |___ includes
       |___ functions.php
public_html
  |___ css_dir
  |___ js_dir
  |___ images_dir

  index.php
  home.php
  profile.php
```

so my question is should I be concerned about moving my php pages out of the public folder or there is nothing to concern ?? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, You can have your php files in public folder

Comment: Is there anything i should be careful about (related to the php pages inside public folder) @GaurangJoshi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that nothing can leave your server unsecured, even in the worst case, it's perfectly fine to point the document root to some nearly empty folder (that holds only the entry point) and have the business logic in another folder.

For example, Fabien Potencier, the creator of Symfony, proposes the following in http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html:

- Source Code under `src/`
- Web files under `public/`

This way, even if your PHP process fails, but your webserver still serves files from `public`, nobody will be able to read more than simple bootstrapping (once again an example of Symfony: their recommended `index.php` needs only little changes from https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/public/index.php to your own application in very specific cases).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nico Haase. I know there is a better solution than mine. But for now I have to keep it as simple as possible. So what do you think am I good enough to go online ??

Comment: I think so - as far as I see, your setup holds as little files as needed in `public_html` and more complex parts in `resources` - how these folders are called is not interesting. The one thing you could improve: why are there **three** PHP files in your `public_html`? Why not use MVC: one single entry point as a dispatcher between multiple controllers?

Comment: Well, ask the opposite: Is "procedural coding" still a good thing? ;)

Answer (score -2):

Anything you should publish such as index.php should be placed inside the public_html folder. Your web server's php engine processes the php and send only the output.

There cannot be any harm come in your way if your web server is configured property to serve php outputs.

If you are using Apache, use `.htaccess` file to further restrict the access (such as folder indexing) to `public_html` folder.

Comment: I think the question is not about whether everything is safe while everything is properly configured - it's more about "what could happen if something goes wrong and how to secure against that case"